# Length and cardinality

Tags: calculus

In physics, 1m is defined 'the length which light travels in certain time'.
And i've thought 2m has twice many elements than 1m.
But today i've realized intervals (0,1) and (0,2) are equipotent.
I was shocked because i've thought length and cardinality are similar concepts.
Cardinality is clearly defined in set theory. But what is length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best "approximation" of length in mathematics is "measure theory". This is an extensive field of mathematics that deals with "sizes" (called "measures") of sets.

You can define a measure on $\mathbb R$ on which the measure of an interval $(a,b)$ is equal $b-a$. This is called the Lebesgue measure, and it fits what you understand as "twice as big", since the measure of $[0,2]$ is two times the measure of $[0,1]$. The Lebesgue measure can also be defined on $\mathbb R^n$, and there, the size of the "rectangle" $$[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\times\cdots\times [a_n, b_n]$$

is equal to $$(b_1-a_1)\cdot (b_2-a_2)\cdots (b_n-a_n).$$

For initial further reading, look up the [wikipedia page on measure theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: Then i have another question. At the start, how could we assign coordinate values to points before we don't know the concept of length?

Comment: @clfmclfm You don't have a concept of *length*, but you *do* have a concept of distance. So, in a 2D world, you simply say "the $x$ coordinate is the distance of the point from the $y$ axis".

Comment: @5sum Length is line's property or the thing which line has. And distance is 'relationship' between two points. Like this, length and distance is different concept. But the distance between two points is equal to the length of line whose end points are those two points. So i think if we don't know the concept of length, we also don't know the concept of distance. If i'm wrong please teach me what distance is.

Comment: @clfmclfm In mathematics, I would say this: You start with the set of real numbers, an uncountable linearly ordered set. Then, you can construct $\mathbb R^n$. Let's have $n$ fixed to $2$ for now, so you construct a plane. 

The next step is you define a metric on $\mathbb R^2$. You *define* the distance between $a=(x_1,y_1)$ and $b=(x_2,y_2)$ as $d(a,b) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}$. Now, you can talk about distances in the plane, but you *HAD* coordinate points even before you had distances.

Comment: @5sum Let's treat 1-dimension for simplicity. We use the set of real numbers R to easily handle the 1-dimensional Euclid plane E1. I think we can't assign proper coordinate value to E1 before we know the concept of distance. For example, we assigned 1 to point A and 2 to point B. And then we should assign 3 to point C which satisfies AB=BC. But because we don't know what length or distance is, we can't decide where to assign 3.

Comment: I suggest length is undefined notion

Comment: @clfmclfm No, you *start* with the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ and all of the other real numbers. You do not need the concept of length to define real numbers. Then you *define* length between $1$ and $2$ to be $1$.

Comment: It's not what i meant. Let me say again. We know the concepts of real numbers and 1-dimensional Euclidian space both. First, we decide the origin point in Euclidian space and assign 0. Next, we choose any one point and assign coordinate value 1. But we can't assign coordinate value to any other point without knowing the concept of length. I agree that we don't need the concept of length to define real numbers. I believe that concept of number preexists before physical reality. But i think this is different problem.

Comment: @clfmclfm I understand what you are asking. The point I'm making is that your question is not about mathematics. In mathematics, you have real numbers, and you define length on them. So, mathematically, you have length on real numbers. How the concept of real numbers applies to the real world around us is a matter of either philosophy or physics.

Answer (score 0):

Just talking in an heuristic way, you can think that the idea of length is similar to the idea of area or volume, which is generalized in mathematics to measure theory. In some sense, you'd like to associate a positive real number to a subset of a set such that if you consider the union of disjoint pieces you get the sum of measures of pieces, if you compute the measure of the empty set you get $0$. This is the closest idea to length. In fact you can define such a measure, the Lebesgue one, in a way that the measure of an interval $(a,b)$ is $a-b$. But don't forget that you are doing mathematics, so don't leave everything to usual intuition. In fact, also in measure theory strange things can happen. If you want a beautiful example look, e.g. on Wikipedia, at Banach-Tarski paradox. Notice also that cardinality has nothing to do with length, also if you think to finite sets. In fact you'd agree that in Euclidean Geometry points have no dimension. In particular a finite set of discrete points e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is supposed to have no "dimension", or "length" if you prefer, instead it's cardinality is different from $0$, so also in finite case cardinality is not useful to find a concept of length.

Answer (score 0):

See 5xum's answer! Regarding this part:

> Cardinality is clearly defined in set theory. But what is length?

Cardinality is meaningful for all sets, which is why it's typically encountered in a first course on set theory. Measure is a more complicated concept, which is typically first defined for subsets of $\mathbb R$ in a real analysis course. Just because $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ are sets doesn't mean that set theory tells us everything about them!